# How to save a nestedSortable list to the database and query the results so the list stays nested upon refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My issue is that with the https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable plugin, I am not sure what is the best way to store the array within the database once the list has been moved and saved. The options are `serialize`, `toArray`, `toHierarchy`. I tried it with `serialize`, and I have not been successful. Any ideas? There is no valid resources that I can find showing how to properly save the nested values and query those values so that the list items stay in the same hierarchy as displayed within the database.

Trust me I am not going to give all my code, but here is the gist:
First I initiated the plugins controller the html markup looks like any others and it works:

```
$('.sortable').nestedSortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    isTree: true,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    maxLevels: 3,
    expandOnHover: 200,
    startCollapsed: true

});
```

I then used a simple click event to get the `serialized` data and I did an `ajax` post method to transfer the data to server side.

```
$('#serialize').click(function () {

    var serialized = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('serialize');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'operationsSave.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            list: serialized
        }
    });

});
```

From there I do the common stuff in `PHP`, I recover the `$_POST` value and I query that value into the database. Again, all of this works. I just want to know what is the next step. How do I query the `serialized` data from the database and make the list inherit the values that were set within the database?